# Programmatically lock, certify and sign a word document created using VSTO?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

I'd like to produce some kind of legal documents (bills, estimates) using VSTO.
I was wandering if there's any way to make these word documents completely read-only (by that you cannot modify from OpenOffice). 
Otherwise, is there a way to programmatically generate a "key" to sign the content of the document ?

In a word, I just want to certify that the content is the correct one and that I'm the originator...

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can sign an office document exactly as you require.  [See here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/add-or-remove-a-digital-signature-in-office-documents-HA010099768.aspx).  You can't prevent the document from being altered once it is out of your control, but the signature would be rendered invalid if it were altered and the nefarious editor would be unable to generate a valid signature without your private key.

Exactly how you do that pro-grammatically I am unsure, but I would be very surprised if the .NET BCL or VSTO did not provide an API for doing so.